# Swift4 Xcode9 Passing variable between ViewControllers through segue

Tags: segue, swift4, xcode9

```
class InstanceViewController: NSViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var InstanceAddr:NSTextField!
    var input: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        InstanceViewController().input = "https://google.com"
        if (segue.identifier?.rawValue == "moveToLoginWindow"){
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationController as! loginWebViewController
            destinationVC.address = input
        }
    }
}

class loginWebViewController: NSViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var instanceview: WKWebView!
    var address: String?
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        var instanceaddress: String? = address
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var url = URL(string: instanceaddress!)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        instanceview.load(request)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass variable `input: String` from InstanceViewController to `address: String?` in loginWebViewController and load webview with this address. I succeeded loading webview but I can't seem to pass variable through segue `moveToLoginWindow`. I did everything I could possibly think but nothing worked. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new instance of `InstanceViewController` inside another instance of the same type makes no sense and causes the issue.

You have to use `input` of the current instance:

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    input = "https://google.com"
    if segue.identifier?.rawValue == "moveToLoginWindow" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationController as! loginWebViewController
        destinationVC.address = input
    }
}
```

And as the passed type is non-optional declare `address` also as non-optional

```
var address = ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but then I get 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' error on `var requests = URLRequests(url: url!)` line. What I found out is, this is caused by value that goes into var `url` being nil, and that means no value was passed to `loginWebViewController` from `InstanceViewController` according to what I understand, am I correct?

Comment: I guess. Check if `prepare(for` is called at all. And I would use always `guard - let` or `if - let` to avoid these kind of crashes.

Comment: You were right about the `prepare(for` not being called. Breakpoint didn't work and I think I found where to dig. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class InstanceViewController: NSViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var InstanceAddr:NSTextField!
    var input: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        InstanceViewController().input = "https://google.com" // Well actually in this line you are creating a new instance for your controller , that will not affect the input value of this controller So correction will be :-
        self.input = "https://google.com"
        if (segue.identifier?.rawValue == "moveToLoginWindow"){
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationController as! loginWebViewController
            destinationVC.address = input
        }
    }
}

class loginWebViewController: NSViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var instanceview: WKWebView!
    var address: String?
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        var instanceaddress: String? = address // there is no need of create extra object as both are optional Prefer  guard let instanceaddress = address else { return }
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var url = URL(string: instanceaddress!)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        instanceview.load(request)
    }
}
```

This might help you :-

```
class InstanceViewController: NSViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var InstanceAddr:NSTextField!
    var input: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        self.input = "https://google.com"
        if (segue.identifier?.rawValue == "moveToLoginWindow"){
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationController as! loginWebViewController
            destinationVC.address = input
        }
    }
}

class loginWebViewController: NSViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var instanceview: WKWebView!
    var address: String?
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let instanceAddress = address, let url = URL(string: instanceAddress) else { return}
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        instanceview.load(request)
    }
}
```